# Android Crop LinearLayout Background

Tags: android, android-layout

In my android app I have a background that is used for sections on the screen (not the entire screen) so I'm trying to apply it to a LinearLayout.  The problem is that this is stretching the LinearLayout to the size of the image.  I want it to Crop the image.  I tried using a bitmap and couldn't get that to work, tried putting my image in an ImageView within a relative layout and couldn't get that to work either.  What should my xml look like?

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="clip_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_blue_w_pattern">
        <RelativeLayout
            style="@style/menu_layout"
            local:MvxBind="Click CalculatorsCommand">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_calculators"
                android:src="@drawable/calculators_icon"
                style="@style/menu_image" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_calculators"
                style="@style/menu_text"
                android:text="Calculators" />
            <ImageView
                style="@style/menu_arrow" />
        </RelativeLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
```

Trying to use an ImageView with scaleType set within a RelativeLayout doesn't work either.  The RelativeLayout size is always too large (scaled to the size of the image).  What is wrong with this xml?

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/background"
            android:src="@drawable/bg_blue_w_pattern"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
        <TextView
            style="@style/menu_text"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Calculators" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try using [ImageView.ScaleType.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)**